# Android text to speech absolutely refuses to work

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm not new to programming but I've never tried to write anything for android before and I've encountered an issue annoying enough to make a stack overflow account. The issue is that the text to speech functionality, specifically the speak method just utterly and completely refuses to work. I've followed the tutorial here to the letter:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_text_to_speech.htm

I've looked at about a dozen stack overflow posts with similar issues and tried the solutions suggested there to no success.

At this point the only explanation I can think of is that there is some or another configuration issue with my actual phone that's causing issues. Some security or accessibility issue. However some random text to speech apps off the play store have no issues and can read text aloud just fine. So whoever wrote those must know something that I do not. I haven't had any issues getting any other aspect of the example programs to work, the phone just will not read the text aloud and I am at a complete and utter loss as to why.

The specific method I'm talking about is this:

```
speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
```

Is the fact that I'm using null values any issue? I've tried messing around with language settings and changing between the Samsung and Google engines to no success. If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Comment: that tutorials states `ttobj.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null)` ...which has a whole different number of arguments.

Comment: Old tutorial. The three argument method is deprecated in API 21+. Yet if I true and use it in an older API it will say it requires API 21 ....

Comment: So apparently tts just doesn't work in Android Studio's usb debug mode. Ended up rewriting the script in AIDE and it's been working perfectly.